Defining random variable on given sample space
Let $(\Omega, F, P)$ be a probability space with $\Omega  = \{1,2,\ldots, 26\}$ and $P$ has uniform distribution
the task is to define two discrete independent random variables $X,Y$ with $X$ being a fair coin and to show that it is not possible to define two independent fair coins on this probability space.
I know the definition of uniform distribution in discrete random variables, which is $P(A)=|A|/|\Omega|$ and the definition of independence $$P(X=x,Y=y)=P(X=x)P(Y=y)$$
Can someone give me a hint how to start this problem? I am completely stuck.

Welcome to MSE. To construct a "fair coin" on this probability space, find a way to write $\Omega=\Omega_1\sqcup \Omega_2$ (disjoint union) such that $\boldsymbol{P}(\Omega_1)=\boldsymbol{P}(\Omega_2)$. With the definition you gave for $\boldsymbol{P}$, it it sufficient for $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ to have cardinal $13$. Can you find a "natural choice" for these sets ?

For the second part of the question, suppose you constructed two such "fair coins": the first is given by $\Omega=\Omega_1\sqcup \Omega_2$ and the second by $\Omega=\Omega_3\sqcup \Omega_4$, with $\text{Card}(\Omega_i)=13$ for all $i\in{1,2,3,4}$. For these coin flips to be independent, what can you say about the cardinal of $\Omega_1\cap\Omega_3$?

Alternatively:  (1) What must be the value of the RHS of the "independence equation" you wrote (when this value is not $0$), if $X$ and $Y$ model fair coins? (2) What are the possible values of the LHS, using the definition you gave for $P(A)$?

@Kolakoski54 thank you for your reply, would a natural choice be  $\Omega_1  = {1,2,\ldots, 13}$ ? I think the cardinal of the intersection would have to be $\frac{1}{4}$ of $26$ because $0.5^2 = \frac{1}{4}$ and am i correct if i say that because this is not a natural number, the coins cannnot be independent?

The word "natural" was not appropriate, I apologize. The first thing that came to my mind was: if $Z$ is a uniform random variable on ${1,\dots,26}$, then define $X$ as $1$ if $Z$ is even, and $0$ otherwise. But your definition works too, of course! Your argument for the second part of the question is right.

@r.e.s. the RHS would be $\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$  and the cardinal of $X=x,Y=y$ would have to be $\frac{26}{4}$ , but this is not possible on this probability space, as it wouldn`t be an interger

@Kolakoski54 thank you so much!

For any subset $A$ of $\Omega$ with $\text{Card}(\Omega)=13$, the random variable $\mathbb{1}_A$ follows a Bernoulli distribution with parameter $1/2$, i.e. a fair coin flip!
Now, if you could model a two independent coin flips $X$ and $Y$ on this probability space, then what would be the cardinal of the event $B:=\{X=Y=1\}$? With the definition for $\boldsymbol{P}$,
$$\text{Card}(B)=\text{Card}(\Omega)\times \boldsymbol{P}(B)=26\boldsymbol{P}(X=1\text{ and }Y=1)=26\boldsymbol{P}(X=1)\boldsymbol{P}(Y=1)=\frac{26}{4}\notin\{0,1,\dots,26\}$$
In full generality, it is possible to model $n$ independent fair coin flips on a finite probability space $(\Omega,F,\boldsymbol{P})$ with $\boldsymbol{P}$ being the uniform measure on $\Omega$, if and only if $2^n|\text{Card}(\Omega)$ (i.e. $\text{Card}(\Omega)=2^nk$ for some integer $k>0$)
